# Overfull \hbox (***pt too wide) of a tabularx in a large page

Tags: tabularx

Recently I want to create a large table with many columns on a page. To simplify the problem, I have a minimum working example like this:

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[paperheight=20.1cm, paperwidth=60cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{XXXXXXXXXXXXX}
a&a&a&a&a&a&a&a&a&a&a&a&a
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

When I compile this tex file, I get warning like `Overfull \hbox (5.00002pt too wide) in paragraph at lines**` many times. And the output is not something I expected:
[image: Output PDF File]
However, when I change the `XXXXXXXXXXXXX` to `p{3cm}p{3cm}p{3cm}p{3cm}p{3cm}p{3cm}p{3cm}p{3cm}p{3cm}p{3cm}p{3cm}p{3cm}p{3cm}`, all things go back to normal. It seems that the width of column `X` is not determined correctly. May you explain why this is happening?

Comment: `\begin{tabularx}{.97\linewidth}` works, but `\begin{tabularx}{.98\linewidth}` does not.  Very interesting.  Also, with `\linewidth`, `paperwidth=58cm` works, but not `paperwidth=59cm`.

Comment: You can use `\usepackage[debugshow]{tabularx}`. Then it will tell you `(tabularx) Don't exceed \maxdimen` `(tabularx) Reached minimum width, backing up.`. The interpretation of these messages is obvious: it does not work.

Answer (score 3):

As noted in comments under the question `tabularx` gives a hint if you use `debugshow`  In this case it is doing a specific test to prevent some internal calculations exceeeding `\maxdimen` and giving errors and spurious results. But in this case it's being over-cautious and backing up when it doesn't have to. If you simply remove the test it does the right thing.

Probably there is room for improvement here but this works on your test file

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[paperheight=20.1cm, paperwidth=60cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[debugshow]{tabularx}

\makeatletter
\def\TX@arith{%
  \TX@false
  \@tempdimb\maxdimen
  \divide\@tempdimb\TX@cols
%  \ifdim\TX@col@width>\@tempdimb
%    \TX@typeout@{Don't exceed \maxdimen}%
%    \wd\@tempboxa\maxdimen
%  \fi
  \ifdim\TX@old@table=\wd\@tempboxa
    \TX@col@width\TX@old@col
    \TX@typeout@{Reached minimum width, backing up.}%
  \else
    \dimen@\wd\@tempboxa
    \advance\dimen@ -\TX@target
    \ifdim\dimen@<\TX@delta
      \TX@typeout@{Reached target.}%
    \else
      \ifnum\TX@cols>\@ne
        \advance\TX@cols\m@ne
      \fi
      \divide\dimen@\TX@cols
      \advance\dimen@ -\TX@col@width
      \ifdim \dimen@ >\z@
        \PackageWarning{tabularx}%
           {X Columns too narrow (table too wide)\MessageBreak}%
        \TX@col@width\TX@error@width\relax
      \else
        \TX@old@col\TX@col@width
        \TX@old@table\wd\@tempboxa
        \TX@col@width-\dimen@
        \TX@true
      \fi
    \fi
  \fi}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]
\centering
X\dotfill X

\setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{XXXXXXXXXXXXX}
a&a&a&a&a&a&a&a&a&a&a&a&a
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: My world is shattered!  This is the first time I have seen a DC algorithm function in a sub-optimal manner.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Although I cannot fully understand it, it works well :)

Comment: @zsLiu sorry the answer is mainly a note to myself, some code that I wrote 30 years ago isn't doing the right thing, I'll check later what it should be doing.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes I blame you.

Comment: I'm so excited to hear that in 30 years, my coding will become flawless.  Can't wait!

Answer (score 1):

Obviously you need a linewidth of at least 215pt, probably due to the fact that you want some content in 13 columns. This works without any error:

```
\documentclass{article}%
\usepackage[paperheight=20.1cm, paperwidth=60cm]{geometry}%
\usepackage{tabularx}%
\begin{document}%
\begin{table}[h]%
\centering%
\begin{tabularx}{215pt}{XXXXXXXXXXXXX}%The maximum without a mistake is exactly {1170pt}. I cannot tell why.
a&a&a&a&a&a&a&a&a&a&a&a&a%
\end{tabularx}%
\end{table}%
\end{document}%
```

The point @Steven makes would indicate that there are margins within the table and that 13 column are too many, because this works as well, with 12 column, and the output is attached.

```
\documentclass{article}%
\usepackage[paperheight=20.1cm, paperwidth=60cm{geometry}%
\usepackage{tabularx}%
\begin{document}%
\begin{table}[h]%
\centering%
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{XXXXXXXXXXXX}%
a&a&a&a&a&a&a&a&a&a&a&a%
\end{tabularx}%
\end{table}%
\end{document}%
```

[image: screenshot 12 columns]